Trying to prove the equivalence of the two definitions for the Gini index. Where am I making a mistake?
The Gini index is a quantity that's often used to characterize income or wealth disparity. It can be defined by the Lorentz curve or a scaled sum of pair distances. Here I'm trying to prove that these are equivalent for a random variable but something seems to be amiss. Let's assume we have a random variable characterized by a probability density function $p(x)$. The random variable can take negative values but its expected value is positive:
$$u=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x p(x)dx\ge 0$$
For the Lorentz curve we first need the cumulative distribution function:
$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}p(y)dy$$
Its inverse $F^{-1}$ is the quantile function. Then the Lorentz function is:
$$L(x)=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{x}y p(y)dy}{u}$$
Then the Lorentz curve is:
$$J(t)=L(F^{-1}(t))$$
With integration we can get the area $A$ on the Wikipedia article in the first figure in the definition section. The Gini index is twice that area:
$$G=2A=2\int_{0}^{1}(t-L(F^{-1}(t)))dt$$
We can also change the variable back to $x$ with $t=F(x)$, $x=F^{-1}(t)$, and $dt=F'(x)dx=p(x)dx$:
$$G=2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(F(x)-L(x))p(x)dx$$
Now let's turn to the other definition i.e. pair distances:
$$G=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x-y|p(y)p(x) dy dx}{2u}$$
That integral contains every pair twice. We can change it so that every pair is there only once and get rid of the absolute value. Then we can simplify:
$$G=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{x}(x-y)p(y)p(x) dy dx}{u}=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)(x\int_{-\infty}^{x}p(y) dy - \int_{-\infty}^{x}yp(y) dy) dx}{u}=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)(xF(x) - uL(x)) dx}{u}$$
If we want we could also change the variable from $x$ to $t$:
$$G=\frac{\int_{0}^{1}(F^{-1}(t)t - uL(F^{-1}(t))) dt}{u}$$
However, these two expressions seem slightly different from the ones I got earlier. Did I make a mistake somewhere? If so, where? Alternatively, if I didn't make a mistake and these are equivalent, how to take the last step and prove it?

In the second definition, instead of integrating both terms in the numerator over $y$ first, let’s integrate the first term over $x$ first:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(y) \int_y^\infty x p(x) dx dy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty p(y)\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty - \int_{-\infty}^y\right)x p(x) dx dy = u\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(y) [1-L(y)]dy.
$$
Substituting this into the second definition of $G$, we get
$$
G = \int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x)[1-2L(x)]dx.
$$
This agrees with the result from the first definition because
$$
2\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x) p(x) dx = [F(x)^2]_{-\infty}^\infty = 1 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x) dx.
$$
